# R script, programmatically batch import multiple csv files as list of data frames (solution)

Tags: r, csv, import, automation, batch-processing

I'm relatively new to R but experienced in traditional programming languages (e.g., C, Java). I've recently run into the situation where I had so many data files to load that I was spending almost as much time on that one task as I was on the actual analysis. I spent a little time googling this but didn't run across any solutions that I found directly relevant (I might have missed something, I'm impatient that way). Despite that I came up with a simple solution to my problem that I wanted to share with the community in case anyone else found themselves in similar circumstances.

A bit of background info: The data I'm analyzing is real-time performance and diagnostic metrics for an experimental system that is driven by real-time data feeds (i.e., complicated). The upshot is that between trials filenames don't change and the data is written out directly to csv files (I wrote the logging code so I get to be my own best friend like that ;). There are dozens of files generated during a single trial and we have potentially hundreds of trials to look forward to.

I had a few ideas and after playing around with the code a bit I came up with the following solution:

```
# Create mapping that associates files with a handle that the loader will use to
# generate a named list of data frames (don't even try this on the cmdline)
createDataFileMapping <- function() {
  list(
    c(file = "file1.csv", descr = "descriptor1"),
    c(file = "file2.csv", descr = "descriptor2"),
    ...
  )
}

# Batch load csv files and return as list of data frames
loadTrialData <- function(load.dir, mapping) {
  dfList <- list()
  for (item in mapping) {
    file <- paste(load.dir, item[["file"]], sep = "/")
    df <- read.csv(file)
    dfList[[ item[["descr"]] ]] <- df
  }

  return(dfList)
}
```

Invoking is as simple as `loadTrialData("~/data/directory", createDataFileMapping())`.

I'm sure there are other ways to solve this problem but the above gets the job done in my case. I'm sure this is slightly less memory-efficient than loading the files directly into data frames in the global environment, and the syntax for passing individual data frames to analysis/plotting functions isn't as elegant as it could be, but I'm not choosy. If you have a more flexible/generalizable solution then please don't hesitate to post!

Comment: Since there's not a clear answerable programming question here, this post seems like a better fit for [codereview.se] than Stack Overflow.

Comment: Perhaps, though I think that someone looking for help with this or a similar problem might disagree. Stack overflow is a high-traffic help destination, the whole point of posting here is to put the information where it will do the most good. If that's not in line with "conventional" wisdom then so be it. And sure, I'll blog about it too.

Answer (score 0):

What you have is sound, I would add only two comments:

- Don't worry about extra memory usage, assuming the data frames are of nontrivial size you won't lose much putting them in a big list.
- You might add `...` as an argument to your function and pass it through to `read.csv`, so that if another user needs to specify extra arguments because their file wasn't in quite the same format (or wants `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` or something) then they have the flexibility to do that.